# Where to put the XML documentation comments for an attached property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-documentation, attached-properties

Assuming I have an attached property defined like that :

```
    public static string GetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```

I can write the documentation for the property identifier (`MyPropertyProperty`) and for the accessors (`GetMyProperty` and `SetMyProperty`), but I have no idea where to put the documentation for *MyClass.MyProperty attached property*, since it is not an actual code element.

The MSDN library contains such documentation (see for instance [`Grid.Row`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.row.aspx)), so it must be possible...

Where should I put the XML documentation comments for an attached property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [article](https://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/SHFB/docs-master/SandcastleBuilder/html/67b9bfab-7cf3-4beb-bd88-85bcff4e8ebd.htm) about that for Sandcastle:

```
/// <summary>
/// This defines the <see cref="P:TestDoc.TestClass.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected"/>
/// attached property.
/// </summary>
///
/// <AttachedPropertyComments>
/// <summary>This attached property indicates whether or not a tree view item is
/// brought into view when selected.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The default value is false</value>
/// </AttachedPropertyComments>
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected",
typeof(bool), typeof(TestClass),
new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));
```

Comment: Link-only answer with broken link.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer is a bit late I have found a solution for the appearance of the documentation during runtime of Visual Studio.

If you use ReSharper and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> then the XML-Documentation that is added above the `SetXXX`-method is used to show for the `Quick-Documentation`.